# How to create Horizontal scroll bar fixed size and center align in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, layout

[UI Design for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AINL.png)

I want to design a horizontal scroll bar only in the center of the view and it should be attached to the recyclerView.
Basically, I want to limit the length of the horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Add a horizontal scroll bar to recyclerview , and set the trumb and bg

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/aa_scrollbar"
    android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/aa_scrollbar_bg"
    />
```

aa_scrollbar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 
    <item
        android:width="@dimen/dpi_80px"
        android:left="@dimen/dpi_20px"
        android:right="@dimen/dpi_20px">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dpi_10px" />
            <solid android:color="?attr/Theme_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 
</layer-list>
```

aa_scrollbar_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/dpi_20px"
        android:right="@dimen/dpi_20px">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dpi_10px" />
            <solid android:color="@color/scrollbar_bg" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

could rejust the para like dpi_20px as you needed.

---

Add a horizontal scroll bar to recyclerview .May this help you.

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="#DF9797"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="#fff"
        />
```

Comment: Hi Shirley, but I am unable to change the scroll bar alignment to the center. what I want to do is the scroll bar track should be in the center only and should be of fixed size.

Comment: hi@akshit goyal,i updated my answer,pls kindly refer

Comment: The only problem with this is thumb will move outside the track during scrolling. Basically, the thumb is not constrained from the end.

Comment: HI@akshit goyal,I think my answer has pretty much solved the question you raised, and now you are asking a new question, Maybe you can try to adjust the `android:scrollbarStyle` and `android:fadeScrollbars` parameters or [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new one.And It would be great to upvote my answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks :)